# why its return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's my first question here!)
Why this function return 'undefined'? Thanks

```
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
selector = function (arr) {
    let counter = 0;
    arr.forEach(element => {
        if (element == 2) {
            counter += 1;
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: Because it has no `return` statement that says it should return something else.

Comment: What do you expect it to return instead. And why?

Comment: maybe [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) works better for counting a certain value.

Comment: I've resolved it. thanks. Yes, I miss return)